# How can I fix this File Error in my Program

Tags: pandas, file, syntax-error, filenotfounderror

I found this error while coding:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'us_baby_names'
```

please how can I fix this?

Us_baby_names is the name of my dataset file.

I have tried moving the file using the

mv dataset function

And also

Specifying the path of the file as

```
data = of.read_csv("/path/to/dataset", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

and I got a

```
SyntaxError: (Unicode error) 'codec can't decide bytes in position 3-4: truncated
```

Comment: Well your second error seems very different - is the file *actually* encoded in ISO-8859-1 rather than (say) UTF-8?

Comment: Yes the file was encoded in ISO-8859-1

Comment: For ease of reading, since you report solving the first error by yourself, you may remove that part and focus your post on the second error. Possibly sharing a relevant fragment of the file as text.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your `read_csv` function:

```
encoding_errors='ignore'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with the line of code above.

I discovered that, there was another copy of the same dataset "**us_baby_names**" in same directory.

I removed all the existing dataset having same name from the directory.

Then run the code again and the problem cleared.

Thank you all.